# When are local variables created in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Are the local variables created during the defun form evaluation or during the function application?

Comment: variables are a concept that exist in the language, but not necessarily in the runtime. If the code is interpreted, you may have a list of bindings held in the interpreter's lexical environment, in which case they are added/removed at runtime; if the code is compiled, lexical scope is handled in the compiler and the actual generated code only move data from and to registers (for example)

Comment: DISASSEMBLE the code and see yourself...

Answer (score 4):

A more useful term than 'variable' is *binding*, which is an association between a name and a value.  A variable is one kind of binding in Common Lisp: there are others.

For a function such as

```
(defun foo (x)
  (let ((y (+ x 2)))
    (+ y x)))
```

Then in a form such as `(foo (+ 2 1))`:

- first `(+ 2 1)` is evaluated and its result, `3` is bound to `x` within the function;
- then `(+ x 2)` is evaluated with the binding of `x` above, and its result, `5` is bound to `y` within the `let` form;
- finally `(+ y x)` is evaluated with the two bindings above, and its result, `8`, is the return value of the function call.

Note that, other things being equal, bindings are accessible from the time they are established for as long as there a possibility of reference: they have *indefinite extent*.  This does not matter above since there is no possibility of reference after the function returns.  It does matter in a function like

```
(defun bar (x)
  (lambda (y)
    (+ x y)))
```

Since the function returned by a call to `bar` refers to its binding of `x` this binding must continue to exist as long as that function continue to exist.  It's easier to see that this must be true in the case where the binding is mutated:

```
(defun bar (x)
  (lambda (y)
    (+ y (incf x))))
```

Then

```
> (let ((f (bar 0)))
    (values (funcall f 1) (funcall f 1)))
2
3
```

There are various other cases not described here.

Comment: This is an answer to a different question. What happens when I defun? Does the interpreter/compiler do something before the function application?

Comment: @Kelvin: no, it's not.  It tells you when the binding is created – at call time – which is what you asked.  And obviously, when you define a function then the system creates code that will, when the function is called, construct bindings.  That's the case for almost any language.